# Python in VS Code for Mac, Multiple versions of Python, No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib

just started my coding journey a few weeks ago but running into issues with using VS Code. I have been using Spyder as my environment for a few weeks now but trying to get used to VS Code as I hope to also learn a couple other languages later on.
When I try to call matplotlib i get the error that module is not found. I went through using the terminal to install the matplotlib and it runs through the process. However it still gives this error when I just run the code inside VS. I try to use the interactive window and it spits that out. See picture of example.
[Error inside interactive window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T25EK.png)
When I run the file from the terminal everything is ok and out comes the graph I expect. What gives?
[Result running file through the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iemHT.png)

Trying to use the matplotlib module but only works when running the file and not in the interactive window.

for more context, I was informed it might be from having multiple versions of python installed. here is a picture of what that looks like. Any tips on how to clean this up?
[choose a version of python?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVM2T.png)

Another Edit. Looks like when I try to install matplotlib it says its already installed and the terminal shows my anaconda install being checked. So i can switch to the Anaconda kernel to run the interactive window and its fine. Any advice on installing matplotlib to the other version of I python I have? (3.12)
And perhaps how to clean this up and remove the extra versions of python.

Answer (score 0):

Having different versions of Python is fine, but you have to be able to understand *which* python is being used in certain contexts.

In your case, you have a few different versions, one through Anaconda (`Python 3.11.5`) and two globally installed (both `Python 3.12.2` and `Python 3.9.6`) with your active version being 3.12.2. This probably means that the version that is active when you get your error does not have matplotlib installed. VSCode helps you to know which one is active for files, but in the terminal you can also use `which python` to see where the active python comes from.

On another level, virtual environments, created by using `python -m venv ...` or something like [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) (my preference), you also need to make sure that the virtual environment and not the global environment is the one with the library installed. You can do this by making it active and then `pip install ...` for whatever you need, or `poetry add ...` for poetry for example.

For managing all the different version of python, Poetry can do that project by project, or you can try something like [PyEnv](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) to help out.

To call a specific version of Python you can use the full path to the python installation instead of just sayiung `python`.

For example, for 3.12 use

```bash
/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install matplotlib
```

Or for 3.9.6

```bash
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install matplotlib
```